# Get map object type - HERE maps

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am trying to get all marker objects from map and do stuff with them. However there are other map objects on the map. Is there any way to check whether the object is of Marker type? I cannot find this in API documentation.

```
var objects = map.getObjects();

objects = objects.filter(function(item) {
    //return item is marker?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I have found it for myself. There are two ways I have been tested and that are working.

First example

```
map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev)
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
        //work
    }
}, false);
```

But what I needed is to get all markers from list of map objects and to do work with them. What I did was

```
objects = map.getObjects().filter(function(item) {
    return item.type === H.map.Object.Type.MARKER;
});
```

And comparing with of map object type to *H.map.Object.Type.MARKER* did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the actual class (or base class if you want to get Markers and DomMarkers)?

```
var markers = objects.filter(function(item) {
  return (item instanceof H.map.AbstractMarker);
}
```